# Cannot run magic functions in ipython terminal

Tags: ipython, enthought

I am using Enthought's Canopy environment on a 64 bit Linux OS. Everything works fine in the Ipython console which is attached with the editor. But when I ipython in the terminal and try to use magic functions, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-29a4050aa687> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().show_usage()

/home/shahensha/Development/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in show_usage(self)
   2931     def show_usage(self):
   2932         """Show a usage message"""
-> 2933         page.page(IPython.core.usage.interactive_usage)
   2934 
   2935     def extract_input_lines(self, range_str, raw=False):

/home/shahensha/Development/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/page.pyc in page(strng, start, screen_lines, pager_cmd)
    188     if screen_lines <= 0:
    189         try:
--> 190             screen_lines += _detect_screen_size(screen_lines_def)
    191         except (TypeError, UnsupportedOperation):
    192             print(str_toprint, file=io.stdout)

/home/shahensha/Development/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/page.pyc in _detect_screen_size(screen_lines_def)
    112     # Proceed with curses initialization
    113     try:
--> 114         scr = curses.initscr()
    115     except AttributeError:
    116         # Curses on Solaris may not be complete, so we can't use it there

/home/shahensha/Development/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.pyc in initscr()
     31     # instead of calling exit() in error cases.
     32     setupterm(term=_os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"),
---> 33               fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
     34     stdscr = _curses.initscr()
     35     for key, value in _curses.__dict__.items():

error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database
```

So, I installed a bare bones iPython shell which is not the one provided by Canopy and tried the same magic functions in there and it works fine.

Have I done something wrong with the installation? Please help

Thanks a lot
shahensha

Comment: @Shahensa what is your linux distro, and which bare bones IPython shell did you install (what version?) that works as expected?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a solution, but just an observation. My desktop is MacOS-X and I connect to a Centos machine to run Enthought Canopy both 64 bit. I get the same error message as OP if I ssh from iterm2, but not if I use the Terminal app. 
I am not sure what the underlying reason is, but may be someone can verify if a similar situation is true for linux. Interestingly I can use either iterm2 or Terminal on the local canopy without any issues.

Update:

I just noticed that the TERM environment variable in iterm2 was set to `"xterm"` while the Terminal app was showing `"xterm-256color"`. Issuing the command `export TERM="xterm-256color"` before running the Canopy ipython in terminal solves the issue for me in iterm2.

Comment: Just noticed the same. If I change $TERM to something that isn't xterm, the problem goes away.

Comment: `export TERM="xterm-256color"` is the [official solution](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469320-Linux-IPython-in-terminal-error-setupterm-could-not-find-terminfo-database-).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Canopy User Python is not your default. See this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-

Update: Not true here -- instead, see batu's workaround answer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP and this isn't the reason why. I had canopy set as my default python, then changed the line added (by canopy) to `~/.bashrc` that sources the canopy virtualenv to an alias so that I can switch to canopy at will. I source the canopy virtualenv and try `list?` in the ipython shell and get the same error.

Comment: @aaren: in the ipython shell, what are sys.prefix and sys.path? Does the issue resolve if you rename (in order to temporarily hide) directory ~/.ipython/ ?

Comment: sys.prefix - $HOME/src/canopy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User; sys.path includes a load of canopy stuff, full list [here](https://gist.github.com/aaren/6006168). Hiding .ipython doesn't change anything.

Comment: @aaren, what is your linux distro?

Comment: Crunchbang 64bit (basically Debian Wheezy with Openbox). `uname -a`: Linux tk422 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Canopy version 1.0.3 (64 bit)

Comment: As noted below, if I `export TERM=rxvt` (or anything that isn't xterm), there is no problem. Minimal code to reproduce: `ipython -c '?'`.

Comment: without using ipython: `python -c 'import curses; curses.setupterm()'. However now exporting a new $TERM doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: regarding the solution in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912905/1157089) - is this going to be rectified in Canopy?

Answer (score 0):

Problem reproduction:

```
$ python -c 'import curses; curses.setupterm()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database
```

This [irc log](http://www.opennms.org/~ranger/irc_logs/public/fink-2011-05-24.log) gave me the idea that this error was to do with libncursesw.

My Canopy version is 1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64. I have installed it to `~/src/canopy`.

In `~/src/canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib` we can see that my canopy install has libncursesw.so.5.7.

My machine (Debian Wheezy 64bit) has libncursesw.so.5.9 (in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9`). I made canopy use this. You can toggle the problem on / off by using LD_PRELOAD and pointing at the .so file.

#### Solution

Replace libncurses.so.5.7 with libncurses.so.5.9:

```
CANOPYDIR=$HOME/src/canopy
CANOPYLIBS=$CANOPYDIR/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.rh5-x86_64/lib/
SYSTEMLIBS=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

cp $SYSTEMLIBS/libncurses.so.5.9 $CANOPYLIBS
ln -sf $CANOPYLIBS/libncurses.so.5.9 $CANOPYLIBS/libncurses.so.5
```